# Resizing BitmapImage wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, image-resizing, bitmapimage

How to get this working on WP7?

```
private static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, 0, 0, width, height);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I scale down an image selected from the medialibrary or taken with the camera, hope it helps. It keeps the aspect ratio.

```
    private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;

        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        var scaledDownImage = AspectScale(bmp, 640, 480);

        MyImage.Source = scaledDownImage;
    }

    private BitmapImage AspectScale(BitmapImage img, int maxWidth, int maxHeigh)
    {
        double scaleRatio;

        if (img.PixelWidth > img.PixelHeight)
            scaleRatio = (maxWidth/(double) img.PixelWidth);
        else
            scaleRatio = (maxHeigh/(double) img.PixelHeight);

        var scaledWidth = img.PixelWidth * scaleRatio;
        var scaledHeight = img.PixelHeight * scaleRatio;

        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var wb = new WriteableBitmap(img);
            wb.SaveJpeg(mem, (int)scaledWidth, (int)scaledHeight, 0, 100);
            mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var bn = new BitmapImage();
            bn.SetSource(mem);
            return bn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really described exactly what you want, do you just want to render the image bigger / smaller on the screen? or access the pixel values of a resized image?

1. To render an bitmap image to a different size / scale, you simple use an `Image` element and set its `Width` / `Height` as desired. The framework will take care of scaling it for you.
2. If you need to obtain the pixel values of the scaled result, construct a `WriteableBitmap` from the scaled image described in (1).

Comment: 2. How to do this?
I have a picture from media library and need to send it via network and I need to compress the size of image(reduce size).

Answer (score 0):

This is How i have reduced the Image size that too less than 512 kb and saving image in Isolated storage,
Caution: Just a beginner in windows phone so pls bear the way i code

private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;

```
  string Imgpath = "Rafiq.jpg";
                SaveToIsolatedStorage(e.ChosenPhoto, Imgpath);
}
```

Here  in this Method i m passing the stream that is  e.choosen and its file name

and saving resized image (images size reducing less than  512 kb)  in Isolated Storage, hope this helps you,

private void SaveToIsolatedStorage(Stream imageStream, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {

```
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
                }
                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);

                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);
                MessageBox.Show("ImageStream :"+ imageStream.Length.ToString());
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

         // reeducing less than 524288 byte array

                long compImageSize = 524288;
                long originalsize =  wb.ToByteArray().Length;

                if ((Convert.ToInt32(originalsize)) > compImageSize)
                {
                    WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
                    int height = wBitmap.PixelHeight;
                    int width = wBitmap.PixelWidth;



                    while ((Convert.ToInt32(originalsize)) > compImageSize)
                    {
                        //  wb.Resize(Convert.ToInt32( wb.PixelWidth / 2), Convert.ToInt32(wb.PixelHeight / 2), WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

                        // data = ChangeDimension(bitmap, Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.PixelWidth / 2), Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.PixelHeight / 2));

                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            height = Convert.ToInt32(wBitmap.PixelHeight / 2);
                            width = Convert.ToInt32(wBitmap.PixelWidth / 2);

                            wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 100);
                            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            wBitmap.SetSource(stream);

                        }

                        originalsize = wBitmap.ToByteArray().Length;

                    }

                    wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, width, height, 0, 100);
                }
                else
                {
                    wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                }

                fileStream.Close();          


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

hope this was helpFull